# Creating a conventional syntax "compiler" for python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, text

I love the versatility of python, but I absolutely hate the (non conventional) syntax (mainly the lack of `{}`, semicolons, and obvious variable declarations). I know that for many people the syntax is a part that they like, and I can understand that, but, I far prefer using brackets to define scoped rather than tabs; I like knowing a statement is over when I see a `;` and it is second nature for me to write a conventional `for (variable; condition; increment) {}` rather than `for i in range (*,*,*):` etc. You get the point. 
So, my question is: is it a totally absurd idea to write a text parser (written in any language, probably Java) that converts a text file that has the custom syntax into a compile-able `.py` program? This would be mainly a learning experience, and for fun, it wouldn't be a serious solution for any large/complex programs.

---

I am also not sure how this will sit with the stack overflow guidelines for a typical question, seeing as how it is partly opinion based, so if you think it shouldn't be here, could you tell me where a good place to post it might be? 

Thanks, Asher

Comment: ``for i in range(10)`` is sillier than ``for(i = 0; i<10; i++)`` ? I don't get it. To me the first is way clearer and much easier to write...

Comment: I'm not saying that it is bad, it just isn't for me...

Comment: I guess, what I don't like about python for loops is the inability to write it both ways, `range()` has its place, but so does the for loop that has been around for so long.

Comment: Yeah, that looks way overcomplicated. If you want to learn Python, then you'll have to deal with its syntax. If you don't want this, just use another language. Depending on the complexity of the changes you want to make to Python's syntax, implementing such a translator may be anywhere from relatively simple to basically reimplementing a chunk of Python itself.

Comment: Writing a transpiler from some custom language into Python is certainly not a "totally absurd" idea, and the attempt is likely to teach you a lot about Python, about language design, and about writing transpilers. So if those are areas which interest you and you have the time to indulge in a learning experience, go for it. But, honestly, there is no language I know of which has no syntax warts. Once you use the language for a while, you will probably find the syntax less annoying.

Comment: I am already decent at python, and I agree that every language has its "warts", but this is just a long term back burner project that I have been thinking about for a while, as I said, I don't have any plans for making this a serious project. I appreciate the input -Asher